# How do I improve the scanning experience in Libre Office?

Tags: libreoffice, scanner

Usually when scanning documents from my Brother scanner I use Libre Office as a front-end mainly for being able to then save the document as a multi-page PDF, add my own text, or print it out.

The procedures involved are rather inconvenient. To be able to scan we always have to:

- Choose  *Insert > Media > Scan > Select Source* (even though there is only one scanner attached)
- Wait for the scan source dialog to finish
- Choose *Insert > Media > Scan > Request*
- Adjust the inserted image dimension to *Original Size* because it inserts it too small.

We were able to create an Icon for the *Request* procedure to speed up things a bit once the scan source was selected. But still, we always have to select the source in the first place, and later adjust image dimensions.

It would be far more convenient to just have a single <kbd>Scan</kbd> button which will then start scanning and insert the image at 100%.

Is there any way to customize Libre Office to ease the scanning process?

Comment: why you don't use a program dedicated to scanning, like preinstalled *Simple Scan*?

Comment: Xsane does the work for me. I believe it is a Libre Office issue, better file an enhacement request there.